# Pointers to member functions in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, member-functions

This is actually for a chess playing program, but the code is too long to post here so I'm going to use a simpler unrelated example:

Let's say I have an object like this:

```
class A{
    int x1;
    int x2;
public:
    int Average(){ return (x1+x2)/2; }
};
```

I want to have a vector called AveragesList that stores all the averages (or a pointer to them) of all the x1 and x2 values of every object. So I tried doing this:

```
vector<int>* AveragesList;

class A{
    int x1;
    int x2;
public:
    int Average(){ return (x1+x2)/2; }
    A(){ AveragesList.push_back(this->Average); } //trying to add pointer to member function Average() to AveragesList
};
```

But when I try this, I get a message saying "A pointer to a bound function may only be used to call a function". Is there a work around? I don't want to simply put value of the average of x1 and x2 in AveragesList, because if x1 or x2 changes, the value in AveragesList will not. Also, my book said not to use public variables in C++ classes, so I'm not sure if I should use one.

Comment: Why do you want to store pointer to member function in the vector instead of the average itself? Pointer to member function is nothing but on offset to the member inside the class, it will be the same for classes of an object.Also, You cannot use it without an object You don't have the object to use the pointer to member function(because you don't store them anywhere). What you need is simply, `AveragesList.push_back(this->Average());`, where: `vector<int> AveragesList;`

Comment: Because if x1 or x2 changes, the value in AveragesList will not update.

Comment: Even if you store a pointer to member it wouldn't update the average automagically.It is not like a callback, which does something without being asked to do so.You will have to update the vector containing average manually every time the average is updated.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously similar to the [observer pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ObserverPattern).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in way of dealing with closures in C++ prior to C++11, so the easiest way of addressing the issue without using libraries such as boost would be as follows: define an integer member variable called `average`, in addition to your `x1` and `x2` variables. Set average to the right value when you create your object, and update it every time the `x1` or `x2` is changed. Store the pointer in the list, and use it to access the average.

This is not as good as calculating the result on the fly. If you are using C++11, a better solution is available:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

class A{
    int x1;
    int x2;
public:
    A(int _x1, int _x2) : x1(_x1), x2(_x2) {}
    int Average(){ return (x1+x2)/2; }
    void setX1(int _x1) { x1 = _x1; }
    void setX2(int _x2) { x2 = _x2; }
};

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<std::function<int()>> v;
    A a1(1, 5);
    A a2(2, 8);
    v.push_back([&]{return a1.Average();});
    v.push_back([&]{return a2.Average();});
    for (int i = 0 ; i != v.size() ; i++) {
        cout << v[i]() << endl;
    }
    a1.setX1(7);
    a2.setX2(32);
    for (int i = 0 ; i != v.size() ; i++) {
        cout << v[i]() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's all this "C++11"?  Why doesn't C++ just have the grace to roll over and die?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to store the current value of "average" ... then why not store a reference to "A"?

EXAMPLE:

```
Class A{
    int x1;
    int x2;
public:
    A (int x1, int x2) { this->x1 = x1; this->x2 = x2; }
    int Average(){ return (x1+x2)/2 }
};

...

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  vector<A> averagesList;
  averagesList.push_back (new A(3, 4));
  ...
```

Comment: This will not even compile. Your vector stores a type `A` and you are trying to push a pointer to A `A*` to that vector.

Comment: I think that your code is in C#, while the original code is in C++.

Comment: It wasn't intended to compile.  The points I was trying to make were:  1) a vector of function pointers is *not* the way to go; 2) a vector of object references could be a viable alternative

Answer (score 1):

To do what (I'm guessing) you want to do, you also need to store the pointers of the objects that that you're going to use to call the functions:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class A {
  int x1,x2;
public:
  int Average(){ return (x1+x2)/2; }
  A(int a, int b);
};

std::vector< A* > objectVec;
std::vector< int (A::*)() > functionPtrVec;

A::A(int a, int b):
  x1(a), x2(b) {
  objectVec.push_back(this);
  functionPtrVec.push_back(& A::Average);
}

int main() {
  A a1(1,3);
  A a2(10,20);

  for (int k=0; k<objectVec.size(); k++) {
    int (A::* memberFuncPtr)() = functionPtrVec[k];
    A*object = objectVec[k];
    std::cout << (object->*memberFuncPtr)() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You could use a `pair` to store them in the same `vector`, or define your own member functor class that stores both the object, the member function pointer, and has an `()` operator.

HTH.